# ASP NET Запрос SQL C# запись в List

Tags: c#, mysql, asp

привет есть код

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            /*IEnumerable*/List<Book> book;
            sql = new MySqlConnection("Database=world;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root");
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM book", sql);
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            ViewBag.Books = dt;
            //
            return View();
        }
```

хочу что бы данные которые в базе записать в List 
Он имеет тип Book
Это модель

```
public class Book
    {
        // ID книги
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // название книги
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // автор книги
        public string Author { get; set; }
        // цена
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

в базе сделана таблица с такими же свойствами как у класса Book
В коненчо м результате хочу сделать что бы было

```
ViewBag.Books = book;
```

и уже потом перебрать значения в foreach и выводить

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Books)
     {

            <p>@b.Id</p>
            <p>@b.Name</p>
            <p>@b.Author</p>
            <p>@b.Price</p>
     }
</div>
```

как то так.Подскажите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adapter.Fill(dt);
List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  books.Add(new Book(){
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]),
    Name = Convert.ToString(row["Name"]),
    Author = Convert.ToString(row["Author"]),
    Price = Convert.ToInt32(row["Price"])
  });
}
ViewBag.Books = books;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо все работает

Comment: @Санитариум Ну тогда пометьте ответ как принятый.