# Загрузка картинки в MySQL базу ASP NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, mvc

привет.подскажите как загрузить картинку  в базу MySQL.
Я к существующей таблице в базе добавил  колонку типа MediumBLOB говорят это тип для хранения картинок.
Так вот как загрузить картинку туда???
Можно посмотреть тему 
[ASP NET Запрос SQL C# запись в List](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614382/asp-net-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-sql-c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-list) 
что бы было понятнее как я пытаюсь это сделать.
не много изменил модель Book

```
public class Book
    {
        // ID книги
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // название книги
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // автор книги
        public string Author { get; set; }
        //картинка книги
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        // цена
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

добавив

```
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

Вариант с хранением адреса картинки не подойдет так как я хочу через форму добавлять картинку.
Подскажите как правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно сделать DTO класс:

```
public class BookDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    // Вашу картинку можно достать так
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set;}
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

А `Book` сделать таким:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    // Путь к картинке
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Далее метод Вашего контроллера будет выглядеть, примерно, так:

```
public ActionResult CreateBook(BookDto bookDto)
{
    string fileName = bookDto.Image.FileName;
    string path = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath($"~/{fileName}");

    using(FileStream stream = File.Create(path))
        bookDto.Image.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);

    Book book;
    // приведение к Book нашего BookDto
    db.Books.Add(book);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(bookDto);
}
```